# Unable to set custom security configuration for Kafka

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying out the functional style of using Kafka Streams and have a need to set the truststore and keystore for my app. Below is a very small snippet:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: blah
          configuration:
            security.protocol: SSL
```

I put breakpoints on the setConfiguration and setBrokers methods of KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties class and setBrokers method get hit but not setConfiguration, thus causing my security config to not get read. Does anyone know what's going on?

Spring Boot: 2.4.4
Spring Cloud: 2020.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it needs to be

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: blah
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              security.protocol: SSL
```